# Is there an error in this web-scraping script?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Whats the error in this script?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

years = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022]

web = 'https://www.uefa.com/uefaeuropaleague/history/seasons/2022/matches/'
response = requests.get(web)
content = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

matches = soup.find_all('div', class_='pk-match-unit size-m')

for match in matches:
    print(match.find('div', class_='pk-match__base--team-home size-m').get_text())
    print(match.find('div', class_='pk-match__score size-m').get_text())
    print(match.find('div', class_='pk-match__base--team-away size-m').get_text())
```

[image: HTML]

I am not able to find the error, the purpose of the print is to obtain the data of the games of the last edition of the Europa League.
I attach a picture of the html for reference, since I do not see where the error is.
Keep in mind that I am only doing it for the year 2021.

I try to get the results from the group stage to the final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Always and first of all, take a look at your soup to see if all the expected ingredients are there.*

---

Issue here is that data is loaded from an api so you won't get it with `BeautifulSoup` if it is not in response of `requests` - Take a look at your browsers dev tools on xhr tab and use this api call to get results from as JSON.

##### Example

*Inspect the whole JSON to pick info that fit your needs*

```
import requests

json_data = requests.get('https://match.uefa.com/v5/matches?competitionId=14&seasonYear=2022&phase=TOURNAMENT&order=DESC&offset=0&limit=20').json()

for m in json_data:
    print(m['awayTeam']['internationalName'],  f"{m['score']['total']['away']}:{m['score']['total']['home']}", m['homeTeam']['internationalName'])
```

##### Output

```
Rangers 1:1 Frankfurt
West Ham 0:1 Frankfurt
Leipzig 1:3 Rangers
Frankfurt 2:1 West Ham
Rangers 0:1 Leipzig
Braga 1:3 Rangers
West Ham 3:0 Lyon
Frankfurt 3:2 Barcelona
Leipzig 2:0 Atalanta
Rangers 0:1 Braga
...
```